# joining 2 form, but submit handler can not work

Tags: forms

I joined this 2 form and the current submit only works for the 2nd form... also it is showing an extra save button :( can anyone help me how to join the submit,preview and delete button?

here is my code :

function productform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

```
switch ($form_id)  {
  case 'product_node_form':

    global $user;
    $uid = $user->uid;

    module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page');
    $profile2 = profile2_by_uid_load($uid, 'main');
    $entity_form = entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile2, 'edit');

    $form[] = $entity_form;

    dsm($form);

    return $form;
  break;
}
```

}

Comment: This is definitely not how the FAPI should be used. Please provide more information about your requirements.

Comment: I need to join 2 forms into one page form, one is product content type and the other is profile2 called main. I wanted to join them into 1form.

please help

Answer (score 0):

I'd sugest to build your own form using [FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) and create the nodes programmatically in the submitthandler.

Looking at what you get in hook_form_alter has of course a good learning effect.

Comment: any pin point example please, I am really newbie at this :(

Comment: Did you read the first two sentences in the above FAPI link? It has a link to the Form API Quickstart Guide. The examples module (http://drupal.org/project/examples) is also very handy.

Comment: sorry for missing that part, quick question, am I able to pull the fields as it is already created in content type and profile 2?